# "Generate scripts" in SQL Server fails on "getting the list of objects from (mydbname)"

Tags: sql-server

[image]

Why would this fail? Some sort of permissions issue, maybe? I'm logged in as sa, not sure why that would happen... Clicking help just brings up the documentation on generating scripts, not any sort of "known solutions"...

Comment: This happens to me occasionally. Just try a couple more times and it should work.

Comment: Hmm, I tried a few more times and now it just hangs on the same step - there's a spinning circle which never goes away, and I can click "finish" but that doesn't actually generate any scripts...

Comment: Try the other output options, like scripting to a file or a new query window. Do any of them work?

Comment: Oddly enough, someone else was able to generate the scripts for me, maybe it's an issue with the specific version of SSMS I'm running?

Comment: Could be. Try getting the newest SSMS 18 version or try getting the same version as your colleague who had it work. I've had similar issues and usually trying it again and again eventually works.

Answer (score 1):

I've hit the same issue and thanks to a hint from https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sql-docs/issues/2377#issuecomment-508506433 I also clicked the "Save Report" button. In my case opening up the HTML gives the full exception, eg.

[image: Save Scripts Report with exception]

In my case it was complaining about circular dependencies. Choosing only a few tables made the export work.

Comment: I'd like to add to this answer. The reason this came up (for me) was because I had two tables which had FK's to one another. Either excluding one table or the other OR choosing to export both data and schema instead of Data Only resolves the script generation issue.

Comment: "Save Report" is key in order to get the error detail!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same generic error. In my case it was due to invalid options, because I ticked 'Single script file', but entered a directory path, not a file path, in the 'File name' field.
Choosing 'One script per object' fixed the issue.